# Regex replace equals characters by other regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

Let´s say that I have an String

```
String value = $$$$;
```

if there´s any possible using regex to replace all similar characters by just this expression

```
String value=\\$*
```

And what about if the value is ****

I´m having issue since I´m making a split with **** and I´m receiving this exception

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 3
```

***

Comment: Escape the `*`: `\*` or `\\*` in a Java string literal. But show your code to be sure.

Comment: What do `"$$$$"`, `"****"` and `"$$***"` each become?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, then yes. You can use `()` to group; `^` for the start and `.` to match anything. Like,

```
String value = "$$$$";
String value2 = "****";
System.out.println(value.replaceAll("^(.)+$", "$1"));
System.out.println(value2.replaceAll("^(.)+$", "$1"));
```

Output is

```
$
*
```

#### From your comment below

> I´m making a regular expresion to extract numbers using the delimiters, so for example 1$$$4%%%5 with the "1$$$4%%%5".split("\$|\%) I was expecting to receive an array of 1,4,5

```
String str = "1$$$4%%%5";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)\\$+(\\d+)\\%+(\\d+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
1
4
5
```

Comment: what I really want is split up a String like 1****3 and get 1,3 array. What do you think it´s best option?. Right know if I do by just split(\\*) 1,"","","","",3

Comment: @paul I don't understand what you mean; you want the first number then anything and then the last number?

Comment: I´m making a regular expresion to extract numbers using the delimiters, so por example 1$$$4%%%5 with the "1$$$4%%%5".split("\\$|\\%) I was expecting to receive an array of 1,4,5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch because seems like the question was not resolved and has no any add of value the question, do you mind remove the answer that you did in order to allow me to delete the question?. regards

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to split with multiple signs like: $,%,*; try with regex:

```
[$%*]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vW0nR0/2)

Characters in character class (between square brackets) are matched literaly, so if there is more character you want to split string with, you just need to add them inside brackets, like for example: `[$%&#@*]+`. The `+` means that the regex will match on one or more such characters.

Example in Java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String abc = "1$$$4%%%5****3";
        String[] array = abc.split("[$%*]+");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

with output:

> [1, 4, 5, 3]